# Why does my PHP contact form not Working?

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I got a problem in my contact form and a dont know were is it when I submit the details I got this error:

> `This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405`

The form was working before the problem. I will provide my code and I hope that someone can help me.

thanks

```
<?php

    $errors = [];
    $errorMessage = '';

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        if (empty($name)) {
            $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
        }

        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
        } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
        }

        if (empty($message)) {
            $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
        }


        if (empty($errors)) {
            $toEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
            $emailSubject = 'New email from your contant form';
            $headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'];

            $bodyParagraphs = ["Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", $message];
            $body = join(PHP_EOL, $bodyParagraphs);

            if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {
                header('Location: thank-you.html');
            } else {
                $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later';
            }
        } else {
            $allErrors = join('<br/>', $errors);
            $errorMessage = "<p style='color: red;'>{$allErrors}</p>";
        }
    }

?>
```

THE HTML CODE BELOW

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">                 
    <div class="row">               
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>-->
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" size="40" placeholder="Name *" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label for="form_email">Email *</label>-->
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" size="40" placeholder="Email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>              
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label for="form_phone">Phone</label>-->
                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" size="40" placeholder="Phone">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label for="form_subject">Subject *</label>-->
                <input id="form_subject" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject *" required="required" data-error="Subject is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>                          
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<label for="form_message">Message *</label>-->
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message... *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Send message">
        </div>              
    </div>
    <div class="messages col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12"></div>
</form>
```

THANKS PAGE CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<h1>thank you, we will reply to youre message as soon as we can!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my code thanks again for helping

Comment: A typical cause for a 405 error is posting to a static file, does the file that form is posting to exist? The code shown probably isn't relevant, please use your browser developer tools to look at the POST network request and copy the request/response headers and edit the question to include this info.

Comment: the `405` error is `Method Not Allowed` [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) - is this running on local server or live site? Have you set any restrictions on allowed methods?

Comment: yes @Bagus Tesa

Comment: There's no php in the form, so this sounds like the webserver you're using (apache, nginx) doesn't have php support. Hard to tell without more details though.

Comment: @OmarALOseimy AD7six is right, though i do curious when you said *"the form was working before the problem"* - did any changes made? like webserver upgrade, moving to different server?

Comment: Where is it hosted.  have you looked at error logs ?  where does teh html code reside.  Please post teh complete file